# Problem with referencing auth_user table in Django with raw query

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

I need to make an inner join on my tables and I need the users last name and first name from the `auth_user` table whose are added to a project. Projects are collected in another table (Project) that is connected to a `Profile` model with which I extended my `User` model.

Yet I'm using SqLite3 so I wrote a query that works well in SqLite Viewer:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, projekt_id 
FROM 'auth_user' 
INNER JOIN stressz_profile ON 
stressz_profile.user_id = auth_user.id 
WHERE projekt_id=1
```

I adopted the query to Django like this:

```
resztvevok = Profile.objects.raw('SELECT username, projekt_id FROM auth_user AS resztvevok INNER JOIN stressz_profile ON stressz_profile.user_id = auth_user.id WHERE projekt_id=1')
```

But when I refresh the browser it says:

```
no such column: auth_user.id
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    projekt = models.ForeignKey(Projekt, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=3)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are retrieving data from auth_user table but referring to Profile class model instance. I think it must be `User.objects.raw(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don' t use the alias `resztvevok` when accessing the `id` column:

```
resztvevok = Profile.objects.raw('SELECT username, projekt_id FROM auth_user AS resztvevok INNER JOIN stressz_profile ON resztvevok.id = stressz_profile.user_id WHERE projekt_id=1')
```